# Laravel routing with MAMP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I don't know if I am doing something wrong but here is my situation. I have MAMP and I am learning Laravel following [this](http://learninglaravel.net/laravel5/building-our-first-website). I must write in URL http://localhost/basic-crud/public/ to get to the home view. Here is my routes php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});
```

How can I get http://localhost/basic-crud/ route/link to my index page? Also when I click on About or Contact links on my home page they are broken because I get http://localhost/about or http://localhost/contact. I hope I managed to explain my problem, any solutions?

Comment: MAMP pro could solve your issue as well. It has virtual host out of the box. Also, you can probably set up virtual hosts...

Comment: I can't buy mamp pro. I tried to point into my project directory but css is messed up and I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: If you are on Mac, you can also use the built-in Apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your DocumentRoot to your public folder in the project.  Your virtualhost directive in your `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` file should look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Me/basic-crud/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can access those links using localhost/about or localhost/contact.
NOTE: don't forget to restart apache.

I'll also suggest using [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead), as it sets all of this up for you and is a great way to manage your development environment.

Comment: That isn't working for me. I must be doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Lets chat about it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94647/chat-about-question-33618658